# Can you block certain commands from a headset?

Tags: bluetooth-hsp

Many Bluetooth headsets have few buttons for a multitude of functions. Press once for "louder", twice for "next song", doubletap for dial, hold for stop, hold longer for pairing and what not. Especially the "dial last number" is the source of a lot of embarrassment. Can you limit the functionality of those buttons, i.e. disallow any interaction but volume change?

Thanks.